# MEX compile error: unknown type name 'char16_t'

Tags: xcode, matlab, c++11, compiler-errors, mex

I cannot compile any MATLAB MEX code due to the following error:

```
In file included from /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/extern/include/mex.h:58:
In file included from /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/extern/include/matrix.h:294:
/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/extern/include/tmwtypes.h:819:9: error: unknown type name 'char16_t'
typedef char16_t CHAR16_T;
```

The only thing that has changed on my machine as far as I can remember is that Xcode was updated to version 5.1 (5B130a).

Any fix for the time being to compile MEX code in MATLAB?

[Running on OS 10.9.2 with Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default, the upgraded Clang doesn't set `char16_t`, which is required by MATLAB.

### Quick fix

This works for C or C++ code but needs to be done on each `mex` command line.

```
>> mex -Dchar16_t=uint16_t ...
```

Other solutions below put this definition into the mex configuration or enable C++11.

### Permanent solution

Options:

- Add `-std=c++11` to `CXXFLAGS` in your mex configuration file AND compile .cpp files instead of .c.  The mex config file is mexopts.sh (pre-R2014a) or the .xml file indicated by `mex -setup` (R2014a+).  **This is what worked for OP, but the next option works too.** Be sure to edit the active/installed config, not the system-wide reference. Try the next solution if you can't tell.
- Use a `#define` or `typedef` to create `char16_t` before including mex.h (see "other workaround" below).
- In some future version of MATLAB, this will have been fixed. Re-run `mex -setup` to have MATLAB reconfigure it for you and it works. As of R2014a, this doesn't do the trick.
- As a last resort, you can always modify the MATLAB installation, hacking MATLAB's tmwtypes.h as Dennis suggests, but I strongly suggest *NOT* modifying the MATLAB installation.

Note: If you are using C and cannot or don't want to change to C++, follow the solution in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22705789/2778484), OR see the alternative workaround below.

---

**The other workaround**

If for some reason you are not able to enable the C++11 standard, you can use the preprocessor to define `char16_t`.  Either put `#define char16_t uint16_t` *before* `#include "mex.h"`, or set it with the compiler command line:

```
-Dchar16_t=uint16_t
```

Alternatively, use a `typedef`, again *before* including mex.h:

```
typedef uint16_t char16_t;
```

If these solutions don't work, try changing `uint16_t` to `UINT16_T`.  Further yet, others have reported that simply including uchar.h brings in the type, but others don't have that header.

Comment: You should change the CXXFLAGS, not the CFLAGS, or you'll get a `error: invalid argument '-std=c++11' not allowed with 'C/ObjC'`

Comment: @flippex17 See if it works when CXXFLAGS are changed instead, as YuppieNetworking noted. I would NOT modify the twmtypes.h file. Sorry I can't say what the best way to fix the software itself it.

Comment: To me, this worked when changing the CXXFLAGS, but my code was originally a C code. I had to change it to C++ (renamed to `.cpp` and add the `extern "C"` before the relevant functions used in matlab).

Comment: @YuppieNetworking Good to hear it works -- I can't test it.  Also, you can supposedly force clang to compile as C++ without changing the extension with `clang -x c++ file.c`.

Answer (score 8):

I experienced the same error, also directly after upgrading to Xcode 5.1.

The relevant lines (818-824) in the file tmwtypes.h, which causes the error, are:

```cpp
#if defined(__STDC_UTF_16__) || (defined(_HAS_CHAR16_T_LANGUAGE_SUPPORT) && _HAS_CHAR16_T_LANGUAGE_SUPPORT)
typedef char16_t CHAR16_T;
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
typedef wchar_t CHAR16_T;
#else
typedef UINT16_T CHAR16_T;
#endif
```

A solution is to simply change the line

```
typedef char16_t CHAR16_T;
```

into

```
typedef UINT16_T CHAR16_T;
```

A must admit that I don't know if this affects any function or behaviour of mex files but at least I'm able to compile my c files again using mex.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I just did it differently.

Comment: I had to do this in order to debug my MEX code in Xcode.  Thanks for this.  +1

Answer (score 2):

Please see other answers if this method doesn't work.

I upgraded my gcc/g++ compilers using homebrew to version 4.8 --> `gcc-4.8` and `g++-4.8`.

After that I changed the following lines in the mexopts.sh file:

```
CXXFLAGS="-fno-common -fexceptions -arch $ARCHS -isysroot $MW_SDKROOT -mmacosx-version-min=$MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET -std=c++11"
```

In my mexopts.sh, this is line 150. I only added the `-std=c++11` flag which is what I guess chappjc meant.

EDIT: This is covered in the update by chappjc!

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant. Thanks for the accept, feel free to upvote too. ;) I think it's much wiser not to modify the MATLAB installation, although apparently most people disagree.

Answer (score 2):

I just add my own experiment (C++ only). The

```
#define char16_t uint16_t
```

was causing some problem in the other parts of the mex file. In fact, subsequently to my mex file, `char16_t` was properly defined. By tracking the chain of includes, the proper type `char16_t` is set in a file named `__config` :

```
typedef __char16_t char16_t;
```

which is also the first file included from `<algorithm>`. So the hack consists in including `algorithm` before `mex.h`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include "mex.h"
```

and the proper settings are performed, still in a multiplatform manner and without changing anything in the build configuration.

Comment: This fix worked for me!  I tried doing the suggestion by chappjc which didn't work initially.... but after I modified the mexopts.sh file, I forgot to re-setup mex via `mex -setup`.  Once I did that it finally worked, but this one and the method by chappjc both work fine

Answer (score 0):

Include uchar.h before including mex.h...works fine.  Also, the answer above (adding -std=c++11) only works for c++, not c.

```
#include <uchar.h>
#include "mex.h"
```

Comment: Some C-only solutions, including this one, were discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22705789/2778484).

Answer (score 0):

As part of XCode 5.1.1 `char16_t` is defined in `__config`, which is called from `typeinfo`.

You can add

```
#include <typeinfo>
```

before

```
#include "mex.h"
```

to have `char16_t` defined.

Answer (score 0):

This post might help: http://www.seaandsailor.com/matlab-xcode6.html

It was easier than I thought. Just replace all 10.x with your OS X version and add `-Dchar16_t=UINT16_T` to `CLIBS` in `mexopts.sh` file.

It worked on OS X 10.9 Mavericks with Xcode 6 installed.