# Mex files using Xcode 5.1 under OS X 10.9 with MATLAB 2012a

Tags: c++, c, matlab, opencv, c++11

I am trying to compile developer build for OpenCV (3.0.0), however I cannot configure my system to mex C files. I tried to follow suggestions from stackoverflow and currently I can mex c++ files, but not C ones. What I did was edit `mexopts.sh` so that correct `SDKROOT` was used, also I changed deployment targets to `10.9`.

My mexopts.sh looks as follows:

```
    #PATCH: MacOSX10.8 // updated manually to 10.9
        CC='llvm-gcc'
        CXX='llvm-g++'
        SDKROOT='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/'   

        #SDKROOT='/'
        MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.9'
        ARCHS='x86_64'

        # StorageVersion: 1.0
        # CkeyName: GNU C
        # CkeyManufacturer: GNU
        # CkeyLanguage: C
        # CkeyVersion:
        CFLAGS="-fno-common -no-cpp-precomp -arch $ARCHS -isysroot $SDKROOT -mmacosx-version-min=$MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
        CFLAGS="$CFLAGS  -fexceptions"
        CLIBS="$MLIBS"
        COPTIMFLAGS='-O2 -DNDEBUG'
        CDEBUGFLAGS='-g'

        CLIBS="$CLIBS -lstdc++"
        # C++keyName: GNU C++
        # C++keyManufacturer: GNU
        # C++keyLanguage: C++
        # C++keyVersion: 

        # OLD
        #CXXFLAGS="-fno-common -no-cpp-precomp -fexceptions -arch $ARCHS -isysroot $SDKROOT -mmacosx-version-min=$MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
        # NEW
        CXXFLAGS="-fno-common -no-cpp-precomp -fexceptions -arch $ARCHS -isysroot $SDKROOT -mmacosx-version-min=$MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET -std=c++11"
        CXXLIBS="$MLIBS -lstdc++"
        CXXOPTIMFLAGS='-O2 -DNDEBUG'
        CXXDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
```

Only after I added `-std=c++11` to the `CXXFLAGS` I was able to compile simple C++ code saved using `.cpp` extension. Here is the code for the file I want to compile

```
#include <math.h>
#include <matrix.h>
#include <mex.h>

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  mexPrintf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

I save it as `test.c` and compile. Here is the output i get

```
mex test.c
```

In file included from test.c:2:
In file included from /Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/extern/include/matrix.h:295:
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/extern/include/tmwtypes.h:819:9: error: unknown type
      name 'char16_t'
typedef char16_t CHAR16_T;
        ^
1 error generated.

```
mex: compile of ' "test.c"' failed.
```

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.

The same error was used when the file was saved as `test.cpp` without `-std=c++11` in the `CXXFLAGS`. I am not experienced in C/C++ but is there some library or flag I need to add to fix the problem? Any suggestions, links would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: I assume that you have run `mex -setup` after editing your `mexopts.sh` file?

Comment: Yes, I did. I am using edited version of `mexopts.sh`

Comment: Another workaround where C++11 is not possible is [posted in this updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22369822/2778484).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When it is not possible to [use C++11 via CXXFLAGS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22369822/2778484), either due to compiler limitation or because the file must be C only, here are some possible workarounds that do not involve hacking the MATLAB installation (tmwtypes.h):

Use the preprocessor to define `char16_t` as a macro for `uint16_t` (defined in stdint.h). Either use a `#define` *before* `#include "mex.h"`, or just set it on the command line (`mex` or `CFLAGS`):

```
-Dchar16_t=uint16_t
```

Alternatively, add a `typedef`, again before including mex.h:

```
typedef uint16_t char16_t;
```

To get `uint16_t`, you need to `#include <stdint.h>`. Or try `UINT16_T` (caps).

Last, if using C (compiling .c file), [uchar.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cuchar/) *may* define a `char16_t` macro, depending on what revision of the the C standard supported by your compiler:

```
/* In myMexFile.c */
#include <uchar.h>
```

Comment: Including -Dchar16_t=uint16_T in the c flags in the mexopts.ah solved all problems. Thanks, @chappjs.

Comment: `-Dchar16_t=UINT16_T` worked for me in `mexopts.sh`.

Comment: An anonymous user reported that `#define char16_t UINT16_T` worked. Score 2 for uppercase, 1 for lowercase.

Comment: Another vote for `-Dchar16_t=UINT16_T` in `mexopts.sh` (same as @Francesco said).

Comment: Please note the uppercase "T" at the end per the comment from @Francesco and others.  This worked for me, but leaving it lowercase as in the accepted answer failed for me.