# Unknown type char16_t: MATLAB 2013a, Xcode 5.1, OS X 10.9

Tags: c, macos, matlab, compiler-errors, xcode5

I've read these Q&As:

- [MEX compile error: unknown type name 'char16_t'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367516/mex-compile-error-unknown-type-name-char16-t)
- [Mex files using Xcode 5.1 under OS X 10.9 with MATLAB 2012a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440523/mex-files-using-xcode-5-1-under-os-x-10-9-with-matlab-2012a)

but the problem still remains when I try to compile a Simulink file. My `mexopts.sh` file can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/alphaville/44f71bcc1e55af4b8c9a). I modified `mexopts.sh`, I saved the file and ran `mex -setup`. I get the following error from Simulink:

```
Making simulation target "MySimulator_sfun", ... 


/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/bin/mex -c -O  -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE    -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/stateflow/c/mex/include -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/stateflow/c/debugger/include   MySimulator_sfun.c
In file included from MySimulator_sfun.c:3:
In file included from ./MySimulator_sfun.h:6:
In file included from /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/stateflow/c/mex/include/sfc_sf.h:33:
In file included from /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/simulink/include/mwmathutil.h:23:
/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/extern/include/tmwtypes.h:819:9: error: unknown
      type name 'char16_t'
typedef char16_t CHAR16_T;
        ^
1 error generated.

    mex: compile of ' "MySimulator_sfun.c"' failed.

gmake: *** [MySimulator_sfun.o] Error 1
```

Additionally, I tried to set the 'Language' in my 'Code generation options' to C++ instead of C. I also tried to add a type definition at `Code Generation > Custom Code > Header File`, that is `typedef uint16_t char16_t;` I also tried to add a `-Dchar16_t=uint16_t` in CXXFLAGS, but the problem remains...

I'm running on Mac OS X 10.9, Xcode 5.1.1 and MATLAB 2013a.

Answer (score 0):

Try the answer here: [MEX compile error: unknown type name 'char16_t'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367516/mex-compile-error-unknown-type-name-char16-t)

This worked for me:
"Add -std=c++11 to CXXFLAGS in your current mexopts.sh. AND compile .cpp files instead of .c. (UPDATE: this is what worked). Some other options follow."

Good luck... I'm trying to get Matlab 2012a to work on my Mac OS X 10.9...