# MATLAB can't see my C compiler to mex svmlib

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction, mex

I have 64-bit Mac, OS X 10.8.5, and I have xcode installed.  I can also verify gcc works from the command line. When I type mex -setup I get

```
The options files available for mex are:

  1: /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/bin/mexopts.sh : 
      Template Options file for building MEX-files


  0: Exit with no changes
```

This is unhelpful. And when I type make, with all of the relevant libsvm files in my folder of choice, I get

```
make
xcodebuild: error: SDK "macosx10.7" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "clang", not a developer tool or in PATH

    mex: compile of ' "libsvmread.c"' failed.
```

If make.m fails, please check README about detailed instructions.

Is anyone able to help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest thing is to edit the mexopts.sh file directly, using your favorite text editor (you may need to do this with "Administrator Privileges").  The file:

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/bin/mexopts.sh
```

defines a bunch of paths and flags for invoking the C/C++ compiler on your system.  It tends not to keep up with revisions to the MacOS.

On my system, I had to make the following changes:

lines 258-260

```
         CC='gcc'
         SDKROOT='/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk'
         MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.6'
```

line 273

```
         CXX=g++
```

There will be many references to "CC=" in the file; you're looking for the ones that follow the line

```
         maci64)
```

But the correct values for your system depend on which gcc/g++ you have and where they are installed.  As you can see, I have the MacOS 10.6 Developer tools installed under /Develop.  You will need an install of the Developer tools (XCode) - see 
[How to use/install gcc on Mac OS X 10.8 / Xcode 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/how-to-use-install-gcc-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-4)

In more recent versions of the XCode tools, the path might look more like:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk
```

But compiling MEX code with more recent versions of XCode might cause other problems - I had issues with char16_t, see:
[MEX compile error: unknown type name 'char16_t'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367516/mex-compile-error-unknown-type-name-char16-t)